# Snowflake session policy with idle timeout doesn't terminate sessions. Even with KEEP_ALIVE=false

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

## Context

I am trying to reproduce the case where a session gets closed by inactivity.

There is 'manual' way of doing it, which is to run `SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION(<session_id>)`, making your session no longer active.

That's ok, but I'm trying to understand how a real life scenario would work. The default idle time is 4 hours, so I tried using a session policy with a smaller timeout, therefore making it more acceptable to make some unit tests.

### Steps

Created a session policy with a 5 minutes `idle timeout`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SESSION POLICY my_session_policy
  session_idle_timeout_mins = 5
  comment = 'temporary session policy for testing purposes'
```

Attached it to a NEW user

```
CREATE USER my_newly_created_user;
ALTER USER my_newly_created_user SET disabled=true;

-- here
ALTER USER my_newly_created_user SET SESSION POLICY my_session_policy;

ALTER USER my_newly_created_user SET disabled=false;
```

Created a connection for my new user

```
const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: MY_ACCOUNT,
  username: 'my_newly_created_user',
  password: NEW_USER_PASSWORD,
  database: MY_DB,
  application: someRandomName(),
  clientSessionKeepAlive: false // it's supposed to default to false anyway
})

const client = await connection.connect()
```

---

Run some query with `client`, just to test if the session was successfully initiated.

---

Then **waited for more than 5 minutes** (exceeded `idle timeout`) with no session activity, expecting the session to be automatically closed, but...

*the session still works*, and it is actually listed as "open" in the Snowflake Web UI.

**I was expecting my Snowflake client to throw a 'terminated sessions' error.**

### Platform

All of above queries and code were performed on Node using the [official snowflake connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snowflake-sdk) at its last version (1.6.10).

---

There are pieces of Snowflake docs that are contradictory to what happens in my case.

> A session policy defines the idle session timeout period in minutes
> and provides the option to override the default idle timeout value of
> 4 hours.

> The timeout period begins upon a successful authentication to
> Snowflake. If a session policy is not set, Snowflake uses a default
> value of 240 minutes (i.e. 4 hours). The minimum configurable idle
> timeout value for a session policy is 5 minutes.

---

## Conclusion

As far as I concern, my session policy should *override* the default idle timeout, therefore making sessions of `my_newly_created_user` useless after 5 minutes.

Am I missing some step to make `my_newly_created_user` to use `my_session_policy`? The docs are not very explicit regarding this. And I don't know how to debug that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if the enforce_session_policy parameter is set to true?

```
show parameters like 'enforce_session_policy' in account;
```

The default value is false, so you need to set it to true like so:

```
alter account set enforce_session_policy = true;
```

Once you have changed the parameter to true, try to connect and wait 5 minutes.  After 5 minutes, try to execute a query.

You will get an error message like:

```
Session no longer exists.
```

Comment: Thanks! That really did the trick. I remember having read something about `enforce_session_policy` but I thought it was only relevant to the Web UI client. Besides, it is described as an optional step in the docs.